# ChromeOS or a derivative in a virtual machine

Tags: laptop, chrome-os

I am planning to buy a Chromebook and wanted to ask if you can install and test ChromeOS or a derivative in a virtual machine before investing that much money.

I hope I will put my question in the right group and would be very happy to receive an answer ;-)

Kind regards
Torsten

Comment: Chromebook, a laptop, has little to do with Google Cloud. I have edited your tags.

Comment: That's right, the requested VM but already

Comment: Your question is about evaluating Chromebook, which does not imply that you need to rent a VM at all, let alone from Google. A good Google cloud question would include what you have built on GCP, and what problem you are having with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buy the hardware, could be a less expensive model, and evaluate it. Return or sell if not keeping it. Worst case, write off as a loss.

On Server Fault, we assume your organization has the capital to invest in necessary tools.

A virtual machine is not the same as actual hardware, the physical form factor of the latter is important. Yes, VMs based on ChromeOS exist, including [several forks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_OS#Builds_and_forks) (CloudReady, NayuOS, FydeOS).

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. Yes, test it and maybe give it back is certainly also a possibility ... Greeting
Torsten